# Panic Button with a background socket monitor

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am going around in circles trying to load a UI form (Panic Button) which will radiate a UDP socket message for help but also needs to monitor a socket (11000) in case another party needs help.
Each component is working fine - Panic Button; radiate UDP message; intercept UDP and display message - HELP.
The problem I am having is getting the socket listener to load and listen in the background whilst displaying the UI form (Panic Button).

I have considered using a timer but that is just taking focus from the UI thread to the listener - checking the socket status and coming back. I think the best way is a backgroundworker which monitors the socket (it doesn't need to report back to the UI as the listener uses MyMessageBox to display a warning.
I got close but it was synchronous not asynchronous and an exception was thrown because the socket was being listened on and open for transmitting on.

The question - How do I load and display the UI Form (Panic Button) and automatically load and monitor the Listener from the load event in the Form

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace Panic_Little_Red_Button_II
{

public class frmRedPanicII : Form
{
    public frmRedPanicII()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

        String UserStr = "Dr Ochre";
        String RoomStr = "Rm XX";
        Double FactorX = 1.0;
        public string IPAddressHold;
        DoubleClickButton button = new DoubleClickButton();
        public int strLength = 0;
        public string s1 = "";

    private void frmRedPanicII_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GetReaderText.GetText(); //gets last user stored

        String strHostName = string.Empty;
        // Getting Ip address of local machine...
        // First get the host name of local machine.
        strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();

        // Then using host name, get the IP address list..
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
        IPAddressHold = addr[1].ToString();
        strLength = IPAddressHold.Length;
        int i = strLength;
        bool Result;
        Result = Char.IsNumber(IPAddressHold, i - 1);
        while (Result)

        {
            i--;
            Result = Char.IsNumber(IPAddressHold, i);
        }

        s1 = IPAddressHold.Substring(0, i + 1);
        s1 = s1 + "255";
        Global.IPAddressHold = s1.ToString();
        // to add on not overwrite (" c:\\..., true, Encoding.ASCII)
        StreamWriter txtWrite = new StreamWriter("C:\\BEPanic\\PanicBtnConfig.txt"); 
        txtWrite.WriteLine(Global.RoomUser);
        txtWrite.WriteLine(Global.IPAddressHold);
        txtWrite.Close();
        //MessageBox.Show(s1, "IP Address");
        //Global.IPAddressHold = addr[1].ToString();
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 105);
       


    }

public static void StartListener()

    {


        // UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        //IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
        // set EnableBroadcast property to true
        var listener = new UdpClient(listenPort) { EnableBroadcast = true }; 

        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255"), listenPort); // 
        //IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.96.69.255"), listenPort); //
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {

                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                Global.AlertStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(filePath);
                player.Play();
                string Result = MyMessageBox.Show("  ***** " + Global.AlertStr + "*******", "*******HELP ALERT********");
                player.Stop();
                player.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
```